# Error: $http:baddata Bad JSON Data

Tags: angularjs, python, banco-de-dados, json, restful

estou terminando de desenvolver uma aplicação Web mas estou com um problema.
Toda a minha aplicação foi desenvolvida em Python, Restful, AngularJS e o ChartJs.
Estou importando informações do banco de dados via python e salvando em um vetor conforme o código abaixo:

```
def consumoKwhLampadaData():
fabrica.cursorExecucao.execute("SELECT round(SUM(kwh),2) AS 'Semanal',IF(dayofweek(DATE_FORMAT(`data`, '%y/%m/%d'))<> 1, 'domingo',IF(dayofweek(DATE_FORMAT(`data`, '%y/%m/%d'))<> 2, (......), IF(dayofweek(DATE_FORMAT(`data`, '%y/%m/%d'))<> 7, 'Sabado','Dia da semana nao definido'))))))) FROM energia WHERE Dispositivo NOT IN ('LAM') AND `data` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`data`, '%d/%m')")
resultado = fabrica.cursorExecucao.fetchall()
consumoKwhLampadaData = []
for data_out in resultado:
    consumoKwhLampadaData.append(str(data_out[1]))
return ('%s') % (consumoKwhLampadaData)
```

Estou tendo o problema de "$http:baddata Bad JSON Data" no angular devido estar retornando o conteúdo do vetor "domingo", o vetor possui outros dados iguais (segunda, terça...), não consegui identificar o que pode está acontecendo, alguém consegue me ajudar?
Preciso da informação dos dias da semana para serem exibidos em um gráfico no HTML.
Esse é o código do Restfull:

```
@app.route('/consumoKwhLampadaData', methods=['GET'])
def consumoKwhLampadaData():
    return app.response_class(Servico.consumoKwhLampadaData(), mimetype='text/json')
```

Comment: Este erro indica que o resultado não está sendo emitido em formato JSON. Poderia postar um exemplo retornado pela chamada ao *endpoint* `/consumoKwhLampadaData`, Wendell?

Comment: Oi Erlon, então, quando os dados são retornados do banco, foço ele a alterar o formato para string, assim como quando solicito buscar o valor de consumo da energia, converto para int. No caso do vetor que está dando problema, acredito que seja do conteúdo dele, já que os demais está funcionando.

Comment: Essa é a parte do código que recepciona o vetor no angular.

`function obterConsumoEmKwhDoVentiladorData() {
        service.consumoKwhVentiladorData = [];
        return $http.get(link.host + link.consumoKwhVentiladorData).then(function (resposta) {
            service.consumoKwhVentiladorData = resposta.data; //retorna a reposta direto para o vetor.
        })
    }`

Comment: Vou fazer um comentário q nao esta diretamente ligado a questao, mas sinceramente, acho que para desenvolvedores python seu codigo assusta, recomendo que dê uma olhada na PEP8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Em tempo: Eu fui o primeiro a editar sua msg para tentar deixar mais "palatavel", mas mesmo assim ficou totalmente em desacordo com a PEP8

Comment: O que você quer dizer com: *'...devido estar retornando o conteúdo do vetor "domingo"...'* - para os outros dias não há erro?

Comment: Sidon, pode ser que o código do python não esteja da melhor forma, mas estou obtendo o resultado que preciso, sou iniciante em programação python. A grande questão do meu código python postado (parte dele) é que utilizo encapsulamento.

Comment: Daniel, Não sei exatamente o porque ocorre o erro, quando quis dizer  '...devido estar retornando o conteúdo do vetor "domingo"...' seria devido o conteúdo do vetor ser uma string. O domingo se encontra na primeira posição do vetor, devido ao erro, acredito que o angular não faça a leitura das demais posições do vetor.

Comment: Resolveu essa questão? Ah, e para que as pessoas sejam notificadas quando você responder a elas, utilize `@nomedapessoa`.